# Is this a proper way of mocking a repository implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Having unit-tested my repository interface, I'm now unit testing my repository-implementation. I find that I'm mocking much of the implementation, too much for my comfort. An example follows:

```
Mock<SqlServerDatabaseContext> repoMock = new Mock<SqlServerDatabaseContext>();
repoMock.Setup(foo => foo.QuestionnaireResults).Returns(new List<QuestionnaireResult>() 
{
      new QuestionnaireResult() { Id = 1, Score = 2  },
      new QuestionnaireResult() { Id = 2, Score = 10 }
}.AsEnumerable());

repoMock.Setup(foo => foo.GetNumberOfResults()).Returns(2);

var average = repoMock.Object.CalculateAverage();

Assert.AreEqual(6d, average, "SqlRepository creativity average failed");
```

...where the actual implementation looks like this:

```
public class SqlServerDatabaseContext 
{
    ... stuff omitted for brevity ...

    public virtual IEnumerable<QuestionnaireResult> QuestionnaireResults
    {
        get { return dbContext.QuestionnaireResults; }
    }

    public double CalculateAverage()
    {
        var testSum = QuestionnaireResults.Sum(foo => foo.Score);
        var numberOfRespondents = QuestionnaireResults.Count();
        return creativitySum / numberOfRespondents;
    }

  public virtual int GetNumberOfResults()
    {
        return QuestionnaireResults.Count();
    }
}
```

The invoked qa database will grow and shrink beyond my individual control, so in order to test the CalculateAverage method I'm mocking as much of the implementation as to make me wonder about the value in this test. Given my inexperience with mocking, would you say  the above is a valid way to go about it, or can you point me in the direction of a better one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not entirely sure about your `Assert`, but other than that it seems ok, also -> This is a very unusual *"repository"*.

Comment: Edited the Assert, I'd forgotten to correct the actual variable in my quest to create the least amount of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that if it executes the `CalculateAverage` method, and your setups return the data to allow the invocation of `CalculateAverage` to run independently, then you achieved your unit test. But consider this...

You have this `SqlServerDatabaseContext` which you are mocking in its entirety. Within it you have a member called `dbContext`. From your example it doesn't seem clear where its coming from. But this `dbContext` is what is actually providing the data for your `CalculateAverage`. Why not mock `dbContext`

```
// arrange
var dbContext = new Mock<WhatEverThisContextClassIs>();
dbContext.Setup(foo => foo.QuestionnaireResults)
         .Returns(new List<QuestionnaireResult() 
{
    ...
});

var repo = new SqlServerDatabaseContext(dbContext);

// act
var result = repo.CalculateAverage();

// assert
reshult.Should().Be(6)
```

so...

1. You follow the arrange/act/assert paradigm
2. Your passing the context to the repository in the constructor, the repository lends its self to dependency injection, and DI almost goes hand in hand with TDD
3. The assert may be unfamiliar, check out [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/). Nice, but not required.

Comment: Hello Juan, thanks for your input. Mocking the dbContext (entity framework database connection) seems like a good idea, as this would de-couple the database provider from the database-implementation. I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Juan said, the part you care about asserting is correct is the average, but when you say:

```
    var average = repoMock.Object.CalculateAverage();
```

you're asking your Moq to do the work. So, you aren't really testing the system, only your Mock, and that doesn't help you at all if someone were to change the averaging function.

The benefit of what Juan's test does is that it tests the actual code for calculating the average using the mocked values as inputs instead; real code being tested with a fake scenario / state being passed to it.

Comment: Hello user, and thank you for your input, 

I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The mock is a mock of the actual implementation of the repository, not the interface, so the CalculateAverage call actually does call the correct implementation of that method, which is not mocked. Could you elaborate? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I've been on a digital-free vacation :-D

Comment: Basically what I was in Juan's suggestion, another nice benefit is that you're not mocking the actual implementation of the class; you use a clean instance of the class and give it the mocks it needs to collaborate with. In your example above, you're instead changing some of the behavior on the actual class you wish to test, which is less desirable than what Juan recommended.